Asymptotic expansion / behaviour of integral function at large x
How can I find the asymptotic expansion of the following integral, i.e. its behavior for large $x$?
$$ \int_0^x \frac{y^k}{\sqrt{1+y^l}}dy $$
I know that the integral can be solved exactly for certain constraints of the parameters $k$, $l$ for $x=\infty$ in terms of Gamma functions but what methods are there to obtain its asymptotic behavior in terms of $x$?

The integral only exists for certain values of $k$ and $l$. The asymptotic expression very likely depend on these parameters. Thus, it would be nice to have a bit more background to your question.

I am actually more interested in a method than solving exactly this integral, so let's for concreteness say $k=2$ and $l=8$.

For: $k>0$ and $l>0$ we have: $$\frac{1}{4} x^{1+k-\frac{5 l}{2}} \left(\frac{3}{2+2 k-5 l}-\frac{4 x^l}{2+2 k-3 l}+\frac{8 x^{2 l}}{2+2 k-l}\right)$$

@MariuszIwaniuk This is an expression for what? Note that if, for instance, $k=1$ and $l=4$, then your expression is undefined.

$$\int_0^t \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{1+x^l}}=\frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}\,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{k+1}{l};\frac{k+l+1}{l};-t^l\right)$$
According to Mathematica
$$\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{k+1}{l};\frac{k+l+1}{l};-y\right)$$ is
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{k+l+1}{l}\right)
   \left(\frac{y^{-\frac{k+1}{l}} \Gamma \left(\frac{-2
   k+l-2}{2 l}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{2 l}{\sqrt{y} (2
   k-l+2) \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{l}\right)}\right)$$
Trying for $k=7$, $l=13$ and $y=123$, this would give
$$\frac{16}{3 \sqrt{123}}+\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{26}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{21}{13}\right)}{123^{8/13} \sqrt{\pi }}=0.235905$$ while
$$\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{8}{13};\frac{21}{13};-123\right)=0.236159$$
So,
$$\int_0^x \frac{y^k}{\sqrt{1+y^l}}\,dy=$$ $$\frac 1{k+1}\Gamma \left(\frac{k+l+1}{l}\right)\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\Gamma \left(\frac{l-2 k-2}{2 l}\right)+f(x) \Big)$$ with
$$f(x)=\frac{l}{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{l}\right)}x^{\frac{2 k-5 l+2}{2} } g(x)$$ with
$$g(x)=\frac{3}{2 k-5 l+2}-\frac{4 x^l}{2 k-3 l+2}+\frac{8 x^{2 l}}{2 k-l+2}$$
Repeating the calculations for $k=7$, $l=13$ and $x=123$, this would give $908.832$ to be compared to the exact $909.424$
Edit
For $k=2$ and $l=8$ as said in comments, the asymptotics is
$$ \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{11}{8}\right)}{3 \sqrt{\pi
   }}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{18 x^9}-\frac{3}{136
   x^{17}}$$ which is extremely good even for small values of $x$. For $x=2$, the absolute error is $3.72\times 10^{-10}$.

Let us assume $x\geq 1$ and $\ell > 2k+2>0$. We can write
$$
\int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t}  = \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{k - \ell /2} }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^{ - \ell } } }}{\rm d}t} .
$$
Utilising the Maclaurin series
$$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + w} }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{4^n }}\binom{2n}{n}w^n } , \quad -1<w\le 1,
$$
with $w=t^{ - \ell }$, and integrating term-by-term yields the convergent expansion
$$
\int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{4^n }}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{{(n + 1/2)\ell  - k - 1}}\frac{1}{{x^{(n + 1/2)\ell  - k - 1} }}} .
$$
Finally, notice that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t}  - \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t}  \\ & = \frac{{\Gamma\big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{\ell }} \big)\Gamma \big( {\frac{1}{2} - \frac{{k + 1}}{\ell }} \big)}}{{\sqrt \pi\,  \ell }} - \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^k }}{{\sqrt {1 + t^\ell  } }}{\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
